# How to fix ORA-01008: not all variables bound in asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, oracle, visual-studio

I want to insert oracle table with procedure but
I saw ORA-01008 problem and I dont know how can i solve this problem.I saw this problem when aspx page is run.solve this problem.Help me

INSERT PROCEDURE:

```
   PROCEDURE INSERTQUESTION(
           p_name IN QUESTION.NAME%TYPE,
           p_tag IN QUESTION.TAG%TYPE,
           p_money IN QUESTION.MONEY%TYPE,
           p_explain IN QUESTION.EXPLAIN%TYPE,
         p_img IN QUESTION.PHOTOID%TYPE,
         p_mail IN USERS.MAIL%TYPE)
    IS
    BEGIN

   INSERT INTO QUESTION ("NAME","CREATEDATE","TAG","STATUS","MONEY","PHOTOID","OWNID","EXPLAIN") 
      VALUES (p_name,CURRENT_DATE,p_tag,'T',p_money,p_mail,(SELECT ID FROM USERS WHERE MAIL=p_mail),p_explain);

   COMMIT;

   END;
```

This page is in asp.net called add.aspx.I want to run oracle procedure add to oracle table.

```
 cnn = new OracleConnection(connectionString);

        string image_read = Request.Form["ImageRead"];

        string explain_read =this.addName.InnerText;
        string comment_read = this.addComment.InnerText;
        string price_read = Request.Form["priceMedia"];
        string tag_read = Request.Form["TagMedia"];
        float price = float.Parse(price_read);

        string pathsw = "/images/" + image_read;
        cnn.Open();
        OracleCommand profile_photo_cmd = new OracleCommand("insert into PHOTO (Path) values (:path) ", cnn);
        profile_photo_cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":path", pathsw));
        profile_photo_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        OracleCommand cmd2 = cnn.CreateCommand();
        cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID FROM PHOTO ";
        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        OracleDataReader dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();
        string id = dr["ID"].ToString();
        int img_id = Int32.Parse(id);
        dr.Close();
        cnn.Close();

        string mailSession = "";

        if (Session["UserMail"] != null)
        {
            mailSession = Session["UserMail"].ToString();
        }

        cnn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmdu = cnn.CreateCommand();


cmdu.CommandText = "INSERTQUESTION(:exp_read,:t_read,:pri_read,:comment_read,:img_read,:mail_id)";
        cmdu.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmdu.BindByName = true;
            cmdu.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":mail_id",OracleDbType.NVarchar2)).Value = mailSession;
            cmdu.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":img_read",OracleDbType.Int32)).Value = img_id;
            cmdu.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":exp_read", OracleDbType.NVarchar2)).Value = explain_read;
            cmdu.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":comment_read", OracleDbType.NVarchar2)).Value = comment_read;
            cmdu.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":pri_read",OracleDbType.BinaryFloat)).Value=price;
            cmdu.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":t_read",OracleDbType.NVarchar2)).Value = tag_read;
            try
            {
                cmdu.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex);
            }
            cnn.Close();
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could indicate which line in your code causes the error.

Comment: Which version of ODP you're using? Check if you're passing `null` value to the parameter, it should be `DBNull.Value` instead.